# WP7 Push notification server setup

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

I am trying to set up a push notification service for my WP7 app.

I have followed the guides and built a WCF service with WPF front end based on the code provided by the Channel9 WP7 jump start guide (Weather Service exmaple) ; http://channel9.msdn.com/Learn/Courses/WP7TrainingKit/WP7Silverlight/UsingPushNotificationsLab/Exercise-2-Introduction-to-the-Toast-and-Tile-Notifications-for-Alerts

This all works locally with the address "http://localhost:8000/RegirstatorService"

The part I am cluless about is how I translate this app to my server and make it work in the real world.
I have a basic public facing server 2008 setup with a domain and IIS7 running.

What do I do with the WPF app to make it work on my server? Is it just a case of changing the endpoint address so somehwere on my server, and where do i locate it on my server.

any pointers would be helpful. i have had a good read around the web but still cant understand this part of the whole PN process. I ahve never dealt with WCF before and dont have much expreirence with web servers or IIS.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You might to check out these posts for a more real world example:

http://benjii.me/2010/12/push-notifications-in-windows-phone-7-1-code-on-the-device/

http://benjii.me/2011/01/push-notifications-in-windows-phone-7-2-code-on-the-server/

http://benjii.me/2011/04/push-notifications-in-windows-phone-7-3-push-that-notification/

You're probably most interested in the second one.